# Mysql join and count foreign key according to its value

Tags: mysql, join, count

I am trying to make a simple reservation system.

I have two tables as `room_types`, and `rooms`. In `rooms`, I have a boolean field, showing that if that room is available or not. I want to list room types, where there exist at least one room available for that type. I know I need to use join and count, but I couldn't put together the whole query. Any help is appreciated.

My schema (trimmed unnecessary fields):

```
room_types [id, name(varchar), size(int), price(float) ...]
rooms [no (int), type (int) (foreign key room_types(id)), available (bool), ...]
```

Comment: If you list your schema, you will get a much more useful response.

Comment: You need to post your schema - depending on your structure you might not even need to do a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select room_types.id from room_types
    inner join rooms on rooms.room_type = room_types.id and rooms.available = 1
group by room_types.id
```

The concept is in there, but I can't write the query exactly since I do not know your schema. I do hope though that you learn what you need from this and apply it to your own schema.

```
select room_types.id, COUNT(rooms.id) from room_types
    left outer join rooms on rooms.room_type = room_types.id and rooms.available = 1
group by room_types.id
order by COUNT(rooms.id) desc
```

With counting (including room types where there may to be available rooms).

Comment: Thanks, count() idea made me get confused I guess. I was simpler than what I have imagined it would be.

Comment: You could count how many rooms are there rather easily, I just went straight for what you asked specifically.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  a.id, 
        a.Name,
        COUNT(b.id) AvailableRooms
FROM    room_types a LEFT JOIN rooms b 
            ON b.room_type = a.id
WHERE   b.available = 1
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY AvailableRooms DESC
```